# Cannot make legend for several density plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to have some density plots with legends, but I cannot add legend to my final result.

```
m <- ggplot(chickwts, aes(x = weight))
m + geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", adjust = .3, colour="green", size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", adjust = 1, colour="red", size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 5, colour="blue", size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 10, colour="yellow", size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 20, colour="orange", size=1)
```

I have used several syntaxes which I have found here but none of them did not work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` bases its legends on aesthetics, or arguments passed to the `aes()` function. Ordinarily, you'd assign a factor as the color aesthetic, which would create the color legend automatically. However, there is no built-in density grouping factor in the `chickwts` dataset, so you have to make up your own scale and labels.

Instead of defining the color directly in `geom_density()`, you can define a named color aesthetic that corresponds to a custom color scale you create in `scale_colour_manual()`, like so:

```
m <- ggplot(chickwts, aes(x = weight))
m + geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", adjust = .3, aes(colour=".3"), size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", adjust = 1, aes(colour="1"), size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 5, aes(colour="5"), size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 10, aes(colour="10"), size=1)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian",adjust = 20, aes(colour="20"), size=1) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(".3"="green", "1"="red", "5"="blue", "10"="yellow", "20"="orange"), name="Densities")
```

[image: Density plot example]