# Can't add legend to density plot with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
vec1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30))
vec2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
vec3 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(180))

ggplot() + 
geom_density(aes(x=x), linetype="solid", data=vec1) +
geom_density(aes(x=x), linetype="dashed", data=vec2) +
geom_density(aes(x=x), linetype="dotted", data=vec3) + 
scale_linetype_manual(name="groups",values = c(vec1="solid", vec2="dashed", vec3="dotted"))
```

Legend doesn't appear in the plot and there's no error message. What should I do to have legend?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378276/legend-does-not-show-line-type-in-ggplot2-density-plot) is another answer.

Comment: Don't understand why you guys are closing the question... I'm trying scale_linetype_manual like scale_colour_manual in other answers, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you put linetype="vec1", linetype="vec2" and linetype="vec3" inside the aes() of each geom_density()???

Comment: Put them inside the aes()? Just tried that, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained already in previous questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164194/cannot-make-legend-for-several-density-plots-in-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378276/legend-does-not-show-line-type-in-ggplot2-density-plot)) about the legends of ggplot2, if you need to make legend for the plot that uses several calls of `geom_...`, aesthetics (linetype) should be placed inside the `aes()` to add them to legend.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x,linetype="vec1"), data=vec1) +
  geom_density(aes(x=x,linetype="vec2"), data=vec2) +
  geom_density(aes(x=x,linetype="vec3"), data=vec3) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name="groups",
             values = c(vec1="solid", vec2="dashed", vec3="dotted"))
```

[image]